# Ocultar por completo una fila de un listview vía código

Tags: java, android, xml

Hola este es mi código xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Lcr_MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/barra_separadorlistas"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_cuerpo_tit_equipo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/my_celeste_claro"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblLTit_equipo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descripción :"
            android:textColor="@color/solid_blanco" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_cuerpo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblLTitcrDescripESM"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Descripción :"
            android:textColor="@color/my_celeste_claro" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

intento por código ocultar a mi conveniencia una fila del listview.

hago el respectivo..

```
RelativeLayout Lcr_MainLayout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.Lcr_MainLayout);
```

y el

```
Lcr_MainLayout .setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

para poder ocultar pero solo me aparece un espacio en blanco. la idea es poder eliminar esa linea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en lugar de utilizar `setVisibility` puedes intentar modificar el parametro de "height" via código.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Lcr_MainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/barra_separadorlistas"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    .....
```

En tu código asigna

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params =Lcr_MainLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 0;
Lcr_MainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

O bien,  "infla" el contenedor  cuando sea necesario. Asigna al relativa un heigth de 0dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/Lcr_MainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/barra_separadorlistas"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        .....
```

Luego en tu código:

```
  Lcr_MainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias .. lo máximo.